# Reformat string to be comma separated and formatted

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I have a list of strings...

```
var strings = new List<String>() { "a", "b", "c" };
```

I want to output them in a different format, like this:

> 'a','b','c'

I've tried :

```
string.Join("','",strings );
```

and

```
String.Join(",", String.Format("'{0}'",strings )
```

Comment: Your first attempt should work. What was the error/faulty output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt should work, but you need to prefix and suffix the overall result with `"'"`.

or,  you could do:

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }
                  .Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x));

var result = string.Join(",", strings);
```

Another option is to use a `StringBuilder` instead,

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    builder.AppendFormat(",'{0}'", s);
}

var result = builder.ToString().Trim(",");
```

In this case I'd recommend the LINQ approach for it's simplicity, but don't rule out the `StringBuilder` if your real problem is more complex, as it can show the intent of the formatting of each individual item more cleanly.

A hybrid approach where you format the content of each item using a `StringBuilder`, then build the comma-separated list using LINQ afterwards, could work well.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close with your second attempt. Try this:

```
string.Join(",", strings.Select(s => $"'{s}'"))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
String.Join(",", strings.Select(s => String.Format("'{0}'", s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt :)

```
var result = "'" + string.Join("','", strings) + "'";
```

or

```
var result = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", strings));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 using System.Linq;

 var result=strings.Select(x=> "'" + x + "'").Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y  );

 or 
 var result=string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", strings));

 or
 var result="'" + string.Join("','", strings) + "'";
```